# How to install OpenCV 3.1 with nonfree module?

Tags: opencv, cmake-gui

I'm trying to write a program that uses SURF algorithm and I know that the nonfree module must be installed separately. I've downloaded and installed the latest version of CMake(3.5.2) and I'm following the instructions from: 
https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/ . I'm using the GUI and I run Visual Studio 2015 on a 64 bit Windows 10.

Since I know that for SURF you must include xfeatures2d when it asked me the source of the code I only specified the xfeatures2d folder. When I first pressed the configure button I had some errors(I've attached an image of them). I managed to get rid of one of the errors, the one that said to write a line of code at the top of the file 
   `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)`, but I still have one error:

`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (ocv_define_module):
  Unknown CMake command "ocv_define_module".`

I'm also attaching a picture of the CMakeLists.txt. Please help me find the problem.

Also, if you could help my install all modules at once, I would be grateful. Or do I have to set as input every folder in the modules folder?

[GUI error and CMakeLists.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Ogy.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Visual Studio 12 2013 for compilation, this has worked for me, but not the other (newer) versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you think that there would be problems if I install an older OpenCV version(like 2.4.10 on Visual Studio 2013)? I only want to run a surf algorithm and try to find a person and compare my results to those obtained by using ORB and LBP. And also, do you have any idea what happened to the OpenCV Q&A forum? Tonight I'll try your solution too and I'll let you know how it went.

Comment: Using an older version should work, however interfaces for some other algorithms have sligthly changed, so code may not run without changes.